# parameter expansion syntax bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to write a short script that will take two command line parameters as file extensions and change all files with the first extension to have the second extension.  I am pretty sure the following script should work but for some reason it gives me a syntax error on the line where the variable `name` is defined and I am not sure why.  I am rather new to bash scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
for f in "*$1" do

name=${f%.*}
mv $f "$name$2"

done
```

The error message printed by Bash looks like:

```
./script: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `name=${f%.*}'
./script: line 4: `name=${f%.*}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are missing a `;` or newline before `do`. Also you don't want to quote `*` in `"*$1"`, since the `*` will be taken as a literal. Corrected script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *"$1"; do
    name=${f%.*}
    mv "$f" "$name$2"
done
```